# Visual studio code cant find python import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code cant find imports that are obviuously installed.
No tensorflow no pygame no nothing.
I used """pip install """ for everything, And it wont find it.
Pycharm does find it but only by downloading it using pycharm.
I have no idea what to do.

And this is the error message:
"""
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'tensorflow'
File "D:\a game 2\python\github\computer\main.py", line 3, in 
import tensorflow
"""

And for some reason i get this error for every file, not just with custom imports:
"""
pyenv : File C:\Users\rocko.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin\pyenv.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- pyenv shell 3.10.0b3
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

"""

Comment: try to change your python version in VSC

Comment: Have you selected the correct interpreter?

Comment: please post the error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Python version used? Press [ctrl] + [shift] + [p] and search for select Python: select interpreter.